# "Aesthetically pleasing" for the other senses?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

'Aesthetically pleasing' most commonly refers to something that *looks* good.

But is there a term that describes something that *sounds* good? I've seen the term euphonious when I looked it up, is this quite a common term? (As a native I personally haven't heard it)

Comment: Usually when something sounds good you'd say it's "pleasing to the ear" or "music to my ears", though the latter is more often used for good news rather than a literally pleasing sound.

Comment: @inazuma "acoustically pleasing"

Comment: *Sounds sweet* covers a lot of situations. There are several descriptive terms that imply pleasant sounding. Dulcet, mellisonant and mellifluous are  possibilities. Sonorous voices are  pleasing, but the word doesn't mean that. It means a deep rich voice and a well-crafted delivery. I wouldn't try to use euphonious at a muffler shop.

Comment: @PhilSweet I added *dulcet* before I noticed your comment. Several of your suggestions would make good answers.

Comment: @bib None of them are very common terms, that's why I didn't post as an answer. I thought a better one would show up.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *[melodious](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=melodious)*

> 1. Of, relating to, or containing a pleasing succession of sounds; tuneful.
> 2. Agreeable to hear: *a melodious voice; the melodious song of a bird.*

*American Heritage*

While the term tends to be used with musical sounds, it can have broader application.